# Microsoft Studio TFS proxy problems in a trusted domain

Tags: visual-studio-2008, tfs, active-directory, trust

I have two domains. TFS 2008 is installed on DEV domain, proxy on PROD. There is two-way trust and both servers can authenticate users from both domains.

- TFS was working fine, and suddenly stopped. Looking at the logs there was a great deal of AD noise (Can't load global catalog, etc.). The trust between the domains (DEV and PROD) was valid all the while
- I discovered some errors with the BDC so I removed it - couldn't do it gracefully, had to rebuild the server.
- While the BDC was down the TFS proxy was working.
- After reinstalling the BDC, TFS Proxy stopped working.
- To make sure, I removed AD role from the BDC. TFS Proxy working again
- Added the role, TFS P died.
- Now there are no AD related errors, sites replicate well and trust is still working great.
- Trying to set up TFS P on another server, the installation crashes very badly in the middle if I give it DEV\TFSService as user to run. If I give it a user in the PROD domain, it installs without a problem - but of course, doesn't work.
- I added DEV\TFSService as an administrator on the TFS P server, no change.
- I added PROD\tfspRunningUser as an administrator on the main TFS server, no change.

Can you think of other components that might cause this to fail?

Comment: this was eventually solved after updating .NET on the TFS server - not the proxy. This is weird since the TFS proxy was working fine on other servers in the domain -- nevertheless, the problem disappeared after the update...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was eventually solved after updating .NET on the TFS server - not the proxy. This is weird since the TFS proxy was working fine on other servers in the domain -- nevertheless, the problem disappeared after the update...

Comment: Thanks very much for the update! If you have the chance, can you please mark this answer accepted? That way, it won't appear as "unanswered" anymore.